# Randomly Add Values from a Model into an HTML Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So, I have a list of words in a Words table.

I want to create 20 (x by x) tables for bingo cards with the words placed in the cells randomly on each card, with the center cell having a fixed "free space" value.

I think the words need to be placed in an array, but how do I ensure the location of the free space?

Comment: center cell mean 10th cell on each row ?

Comment: No, sorry. Center cell depends on the user choosing the size of the bingo card (5x5, 6x6, etc). There will be 20 or so cards that need to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%
  cell_length = n 
  row_length = m
  if m * n % 2 == 0
    middle_cell = (m * n)/2 
  else
    middle_cell = (m * n + 1) /2
  end
  count = 0

 %>
  <table>
    <% for i in 1..m %>
  <tr>
    <% for j in 1..n %>
    <% count +=1 %>
    <td>
      <%= count == middle_cell ? nil : 'word' %>
    <td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
```